# SQL join with duplicate values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I realized I made an error in my last post, this should be more clear.

Say I have a table with IDs and current IDs:

```
tbl_id
id   cur_id   value
aa    zz        5
zz    zz        10
bb    yy        2
yy    yy        11
```

Say I have another table with prices:

```
tbl_price
id    price
aa      200
bb      100
```

I need to return the price and value of the `cur_id` associated with each `id` in `tbl_price`:

```
cur_id   value   price
zz        10       200
yy        11       100
```

The issue I'm having is returning the correct `value`.  When I do an inner join:

```
SELECT
  tbl_id.cur_id,
  tbl_id.value,
  tbl_price.price
FROM
  tbl_price
INNER JOIN tbl_id
  ON tbl_id.id = tbl_price.id
```

This gives me these results:

```
cur_id   value   price
zz        5       200
yy        2       100
```

I get why this happens because of the way the join works.  However, I am not sure how to then re-join the table again to get the appropriate `value` where `tbl_id.id = tbl_id.cur_id`.  Do I simply re-join the table again someway?

Comment: It's not, I need it to return the values where the id = cur_id, not the one on the row where the id <> cur_id.  For example, id = aa has a value of 5.  However, it's cur_id is zz, which has a value of 10.  I need to return that ten.

Comment: I finally see what you mean - I was thrown off by the typo in the original post. Now I see what you are trying to do.

Comment: Sorry abut that, thanks for your help.  I had a major brain-lock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need one more self join to get the results that you want:

```
SELECT
  i1.cur_id,
  i2.value,
  p.price
FROM
  tbl_price p
INNER JOIN tbl_id i1 ON i1.id = p.id
INNER JOIN tbl_id i2 ON i1.cur_id = i2.id
```

The idea is to join the table of IDs again, and grab the one-away IDs from that second join.

[Demo on SQLFiddle.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8c431/7)

Comment: Thank you, I just managed to do the same thing on SQLFiddle, and this confirms what I was thinking.  Now that I'm just re-joining the table as you showed, it works fine!  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a where statement:

```
INNER JOIN tbl_id
  ON tbl_id.id = tbl_price.id 
  WHERE tbl_id.id = tbl_id.cur_id
```